# Storing multiple Models result in JSON in SequelizeJS

Tags: json, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to SequelizeJS. My question is how store multiple model's result in json. I have called 2 models `Users` and `Friends` and I want to get both model's result in JSON. I am trying to return `return res.json({"OnlineUsers": onlineUsers, "onlineFriends": onlineFriends});` both result in a single JSON, but not getting result.

Here is how my controller looks like

```
'use strict';

var models = require('../models');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

exports.search = function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.searchType === "OnlineUsers") {
        var user = new models.Users();
        var onlineUsers = user.onlineUsers();
        var attributes = {"id": '', "username": "", "role": ""};
        var onlineUsers = models.Users.findAll({
            attributes: Object.keys(attributes).concat([
                [Sequelize.literal("IF(Users.lastSeen < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 0, 1)"), 'isSeen'],
            ]),
        }).then(onlineUsers => {
            return onlineUsers;
        });;
        var onlineFriends = models.Friends.findAll({
            attributes: Object.keys(attributes).concat([
                [Sequelize.literal("IF(Users.lastSeen < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 0, 1)"), 'isSeen'],
            ]),
        }).then(onlineFriends => {
            return onlineFriends;
        });
        return res.json({"OnlineUsers": onlineUsers, "onlineUsers": onlineFriends});
    }
    //return res.json({searchResult: "test"});
};
```

Can anyone help me or guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to nest the queries, remember that node.js is asynchronous so after doing the first query you do the second one, and after that you return the response with both objects. Something like this:

```
exports.search = function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.searchType === "OnlineUsers") {
    var user = new models.Users();
    var onlineUsers = user.onlineUsers();
    var attributes = {"id": '', "username": "", "role": ""};
    models.Users.findAll({
        attributes: Object.keys(attributes).concat([
            [Sequelize.literal("IF(Users.lastSeen < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 0, 1)"), 'isSeen'],
        ]),
    }).then(onlineUsers => {
        return models.Friends.findAll({
            attributes: Object.keys(attributes).concat([
                [Sequelize.literal("IF(Users.lastSeen < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), 0, 1)"), 'isSeen'],
            ]),
        }).then(onlineFriends => {
            res.json({"OnlineUsers": onlineUsers, "onlineFriends": onlineFriends});

        });
    });;   
  }
};
```